# Multi-threaded Ping Script in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, for-loop, ping

I'm very new to multi-threaded process in python. I tried many ways but I just don't understand it very well I guess!

Anybody knows how to make this script multi-threaded?

```
import platform
import subprocess
import os
with open(os.devnull, "wb") as limbo:
    for n in range(1, 240):
        ip="192.168.1.{0}".format(n)
        param = '-n' if platform.system().lower() == 'windows' else '-c'
        result=subprocess.Popen(["ping", param, "1", "-w", "200", ip], stdout=limbo, stderr=limbo).wait()
        if result:
            print(ip, "inactive")
        else:
            print(ip, "active")
```

Or a good tutorial on how to make multi-threaded process in python 3?

Thanks.